# The 'FindConfigFiles' task could not be initialized

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to build a project in Visual Studio 2015 and I am getting the following errors:

"The 'FindConfigFiles' task could not be initialized with its input parameters."

"The 'IsFileSystemCaseSensitive' parameter is not supported by the 'FindConfigFiles' task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property."

I'm not sure what this means. I don't know what the FindConfigFiles task is or what the IsFileSystemCaseSensitive parameter is.

Can someone please help me troubleshoot this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem here. I solved it updating TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015  [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do two things to get this fixed for me with AzureDev Ops, a search that brought me to this.

First, remove lines that look like this:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />
```

There were a few of those lines, what you are looking for is the $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32) variable and TypeScript.

Second, change this from 2.2 to 3.9 (latest version as of this comment.

```
TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.9</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```